# MVC 6 dependency injection - to use or not to use

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am developing a simple project in MVC 6 and bit confused about whether to use DI or not.

I have a view that POSTs to an action - AddData(). Now inside AddData() action I instantiate a couple of classes, say Class1 and Class2, and then invoke their methods to get the job done.

Now my confusion is - In MVC 5 I used to create local instances of Class1 and Class2 inside the action and then call methods on them. This was without any DI.

In MVC 6 do I need to DI Class1 and Class2 in the controller? They are needed only in AddData() action. So is this situation good for DI or traditional local objects would be better?

Please clarify.

Comment: You don't *need* to use DI for anything - it's just one way of getting things done and for simple cases it might be a bit overkill.

Answer (score 2):

Dependency injection is a *tool on your developer toolbox* that should be used when needed. It will allow you to follow principles like SOLID, which will make your application design better, and it will be of invaluable help if you plan to do unit testing.

> IMHO it is a great thing that dependency injection is now fully
>   integrated across the whole ASP 5 pipeline. This way, whenever you
>   need it, you won't have to fight the framework as the seam for your
>   code is already there.

But the fact that you can now use it, doesn't mean you should *always* use it. Use your judgement!

- If you are writing some throwaway code or a very simple app, and you really think dependency injection is overkill, then don't use it. ***But at least you have taken a conscious decision!***

Of course, the easier it is to apply DI, the more you might end up using it even for simple projects or throwaway code.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to do so, so that in case you want to test your app later on, you can substitute with mocks, for instance. However, if you do not care about testing or if the app is really simple, then I don't see a reason against simply instantiating them inside the controller.

Comment: I'd tend to agree with this.  Your 'simple' app always has the potential to grow and you end up down a rabbit hole if you don't.  I personally use DI for every project now, it saves on the class instantiations.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what "Class1" and "Class2" are used for, this can't really be answered.

- If they are models, then no, you wouldn't use DI.
- If they are services/utilities, then yes, ideally use DI.

However - there's no difference in the architecture of DI between MVC5 and MVC6, so if you are not using DI in MVC5 then there's no reason to suddenly need to when you move to MVC6 unless you want to improve your practices.

Note there are some 'simple' IoC/DI frameworks that make this very easy and you can always use "poor man's DI" where you have a constructor with the class and one without, eg:

```
public Controller1() 
{
    this.class1 = new Class1();
}

public Controller1(Class1 class1)
{
    this.class1 = class1;
}
```

(many people discourage this, but it's an option)